# angularjs change in model renders only on clicking somewhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a search suggestion functionality using firebase and angular js. Basically on key up of a search input box, I call the below function:

```
scope.suggestString = {};

    scope.search = function(){
        scope.suggestString = {};

        firebaseDb.ref("users")
        .orderByChild("Name")
        .startAt(scope.searchedString)
        .endAt(scope.searchedString + "\uf8ff")
        .on("value", function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                if(scope.suggestString.hasOwnProperty(childSnapshot.key) == false){
                    scope.suggestString[childSnapshot.key] = childSnapshot;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchedString" ng-keyup="search()">                   

    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="(key,item) in suggestString">
         <a href="#/home/{{key}}">{{item.val().firstName}}</a>
      </li> 
    </ul>

</form>
```

The code works , the call goes to firebase and fetches the records but I have to click somewhere in search input box for the suggestions to be displayed.
I tried using scope.$apply() but its not working .Its says already applying scope

Comment: Which part of the firebase code is the async portion which makes a request?

Comment: @FrankModica updated the question again had by mistake added ng-click instead of ng-keyup.. the call to db is going smooth but rendering requires clicks

Comment: Yeah I'm asking which part is the actual response from the async call, because chances are that is the part you have to wrap with `$apply`, because Angular may not know about these requests if they are not going through the `$http` service

Comment: ' snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {' is the callback from async call , btw its working now after using scope.$apply inside this code . however console shows error too [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: Don't trigger the digest cycle *inside* the forEach callback, trigger it right *after* the forEach.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use something like:

```
<input ng-model="searchedString" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" type="text">
```

on input box, which will update ng-model (searchString) with search string in input element, after 1 second delay of typing.

After that you can put something like:

```
scope.$watch('searchedString', (newVal,oldVal)=>{
     scope.suggestString = {};

        if(scope.searchedString.length <3){
            return;
        }

        firebaseDb.ref("users")
        .orderByChild("Name")
        .startAt(scope.searchedString)
        .endAt(scope.searchedString + "\uf8ff")
        .on("value", function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                if(scope.suggestString.hasOwnProperty(childSnapshot.key) == false){
                    scope.suggestString[childSnapshot.key] = childSnapshot;
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Now it should work if your code for getting data is correct.

Comment: Are you sure this would work? Maybe I'm missing something, but if the actual problem is that there is an async process happening that Angular doesn't know about, then when the response arrives, the `.on(...)` would still run outside of Angular's digest cycle and it would need to be triggered, no?

Comment: could be I misunderstood, but even then I think you wouldn't need to trigger manually digest cycle, I rather use promises .then() instead of .on() it should update suggestString fine without any manual digest cycle

Comment: Yeah, to do that I think you'd have to wrap that whole firebase call in a function that returns a promise from the `$q` service.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't know about this async call, so you have to trigger a digest. You can do that safely without getting a console error by calling `$evalAsync` after you get the response:

```
// ...
.on("value", function (snapshot) {
  scope.$evalAsync(function () {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      if (scope.suggestString.hasOwnProperty(childSnapshot.key) == false) {
        scope.suggestString[childSnapshot.key] = childSnapshot;
      }
    })
  });
});
```

But I suspect `scope.$apply` will be fine too, if you do it outside the loop as I am doing above.

Another option is to wrap all of this firebase functionality into a separate function (possibly in a service), and return a promise from that function using the `$q` service, and resolve the firebase response. Then you won't have to manually trigger a digest, since Angular knows about the `$q` service.

Answer (score -1):

[Safe apply](https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js) was the thing I was looking for, the search is smooth now.

Comment: I would really suggest using my solution, because you should avoid using $scope.$apply

Comment: `$evalAsync` is kind of like a built in version of safe apply. No need to bring in external code. @pegla What's wrong with `$apply`? Isn't its purpose to alert Angular of changes coming from outside the Angular world? Directives that deal with external plugins use this all the time.